# How to add angular-pdf in ionic2?

Tags: angular, pdf, ionic2

I want to add angular-pdf to show pdf in my ionic 2, but found most setup are based on ionic 1. for example, after copying angular-pdf.js into my project, the instructions said "Include the directive as a dependency when defining the angular app":

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['pdf']);
```

but in ionic 2, how can I add angular-pdf as library so that I can use ng-pdf tag?

Comment: looks like it is an angularjs module..it wont be compatible with angular 2..you could look for angular 2 alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Angular2 Wrapper for pdfjs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer

OR

You can install [pdfjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) from npm, and use it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
npm install ng2-pdf-viewer --save
```

Add PdfViewerModule to your module's imports

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer'; // <- Here

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, PdfViewerModule], // <- Here
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

class AppModule {}
```

then use it on your html

```
 <pdf-viewer [src]="your_pdf" [render-text]="true" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>
```